# Why there is no mоvb and mоvw instructions in MMX set?

Tags: simd, cpu-architecture, mmx

There is mоvq and mоvd, but mоvb and mоvw aren't exist. Why? Don't we need to mоve bytes and words?

Comment: MMX is (was) for moving a lot of memory at a time efficiently.  Why would you want to move a single byte through those registers?  If this is just a random question looking for orthagonal code, great, but are you attempting to do something with these byte moves?

Comment: I wish I had `movw` to an `xmm` register, for LUT lookups.  (for par2 GF16 multiply).  I've been doing `movd` and then `pinsrw`, but if I pack the LUT of 16bit values into 16bits per element, the `movd`s can cross cachelines.  (The old non-simd code used a zero-padded LUT, which I might keep since it only takes 2kiB of L1 cache.  https://github.com/pcordes/par2-asm-experiments/blob/master/asm-pinsrw.s)